# Spring JPA transaction error for Stream query using CompletableFuture

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following code:

```
public void getAllData(List<Pair<Long, Long>> minMaxPairList) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Queue<String> globalQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();
    CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<?>[minMaxPairList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < minMaxPairList.size(); i++) {
        Pair<Long, Long> minMaxPair = minMaxPairList.get(i);
        futures[i] = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> dbCall(minMaxPair))
                .thenAccept(globalQueue::add);
    }
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
    for (CompletableFuture<?> completableFuture : futures) {
        logger.info("Result: {}",(String)completableFuture.get());
    }
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public String dbCall(Pair<Long, Long> minMaxPair) {
    try (Stream<MyObject> returnedDataList = myRepository
            .getAllDataInStream(minMaxPair.getFirst(), minMaxPair.getSecond())) {
        
        //code to process the returnedDataList
    }
    return "Data information retrieved for keys between "+minMaxPair.getFirst()+" , "+
            minMaxPair.getSecond();
}
```

When running the above code I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.
```

If I run the same code without completableFuture then the code works fine but I want to run the code using CompletableFuture. I even tried setting @Transactional with readOnly as true on the Repository call as well. But it didn't help.

Any help in solving this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is described in [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html):  In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with `@Transactional`

Comment: move `dbCall` to another service class. Another option is to create `TransactionService` with `@Transactional <T> T invoke(@NonNull Supplier<T> supplier) {return supplier.get();}`